# Show that $(\lambda v= \vec{0})\Rightarrow \lambda=0$ or $v=\vec{0}$ Vector-space

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\lambda \neq 0$ then $v= 1v=(\lambda\lambda^{-1})v=\lambda v \lambda^{-1}v=\vec{0}\lambda^{-1}v=\vec{0}$

Since $\vec{0}x=\vec{0},\forall x\in V$

But what if $v\neq \vec{0}$

Comment: If a scalar multiple of a nonzero vector is the zero vector, the scalar must be $0$

Comment: Yes I want to prove that, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show: $$\alpha \cdot x=0 \Rightarrow \alpha = 0 \ or \ x=0$$

---

Let $\alpha \cdot x=0$

If $\alpha = 0$ we are done

So let $\alpha \neq 0$

Then $\alpha^{-1}$ exists and

$x=1\cdot x=(\alpha^{-1}\cdot\alpha)\cdot x=\alpha^{-1}\cdot(\alpha\cdot x)=\alpha^{-1}\cdot 0=0$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\lambda \vec v = \vec 0$.

If $\lambda \not= 0$ then $\vec v = \frac{1}\lambda \lambda \vec 0 = \vec 0$.

Otherwise $\lambda = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that $\lambda\neq0\implies \vec v=\vec 0$ is enough. It shows that $\lambda$ and $\vec v$ can't be non-zero simultaneously, and that's all we care about.

Answer (score 0):

If $v \neq \vec{0}$ then there exists at least one $v_i\neq 0$. We have $\lambda\cdot v_i=0$, which means $\lambda=0$.